# Why does ISFILTERED() always return true when nothing is selected but HASONEFILTER() works

Tags: powerbi, dax

When I use `ISFILTERED` for some reason it constantly returns true when nothing is selected, but when I change it to HASONEFILTER it returns the correct value.

```
isPartnerFiltered = 
    IF ( ISFILTERED(partner[partner_name]) = TRUE(),1,0)
```

[image]

```
isPartnerFiltered = 
    IF ( HASONEFILTER(partner[partner_name]) = TRUE(),1,0)
```

[image]

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: partner table is somehow connected to some fact table? Then Think of it in terms of table expansion. Then In this case, Any column in expanded version of fact table is filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measure isPartnerFiltered will indicate if there is a filter on it. Using your code, and a basic example:

```
isPartnerFiltered = 
    IF ( ISFILTERED(partner[partner_name]) = TRUE(),1,0)
```

[image]

It will return 0. However, something must be filtered on it somewhere, not just by the slicer. In this next example, the name 'three' on the table has been clicked on, but the slicer is still showing all:

[image]

Confirm that the partner name isn't somehow selected in your report, as some external context is affecting the result.